# GSuite OAuth Client IDs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-workspace, clientid

Is there a way to see what project relates to an OAuth client ID? That or is there a way to show all projects and all their credentials if we're G Suite admins?

We have an OAuth client ID but can't seem to find where it's origin is from :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following URL:

```
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/[your-client-id]
```

If you open it, replace `your-client-id` with your own Client ID, Google Cloud will manage to find the project it belongs to.

Then, there are two scenarios:

1. If your account has enough permission to manage that Client ID, you will see the settings page of your OAuth app. The project it belongs to will be in the upper left of the Google Cloud console.
2. If your account doesn't have enough permission, the Google Cloud console will throw an error saying something like: `There was an error while loading /apis/credentials/oauthclient/[client-id]?project=[project-id]&folder=&organizationId=. Please try again. to view the page, you will see which project it belongs to.`

   So you can still have the project-id if you don't have permission to manage the Client ID.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that but it tries to find that client ID under the most recent project I was viewing rather than search the domain as a whole :( --  `There was an error while loading /apis/credentials/oauthclient/[client-id]?project=[recent project viewed]&folder=&organizationId=. Please try again.`